# Bootstrap Modal and responsive datatables

Tags: datatables, xpages, bootstrap-modal

In an XPages application I am using Bootstrap modal and the datatables plugin. On the datatables website I have read to recalculate the responsiveness when loading the table in a Bootstrap modal e.g.:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); 
$('#example').css( 'display', 'table' );
table.responsive.recalc();
```

Because I am working with XPages my ID's are dynamic So I have to call a helper function:

```
var table = x$('#{id:tableObj}').DataTable();
x$('#{id:tableObj}').css( 'display', 'table' );
table.responsive.recalc();
```

So my final code looks like:

```
 x$('#{id:bootstrapModal}').modal('show');var table =
 x$('#{id:tableObj}').DataTable();x$('#{id:tableObj}').css( 'display',
 'table' );table.responsive.recalc();
```

`id:tableObj` is the id of the `xp:table` control that resides in a custom control.

The good thing is that it renders the first table in the dialog as a datatables table, but not responsive.

Another bad thing is that only the first table is rendered as a DataTables table, and not other tables (multiple custom controls in the dialog.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no need to do `css( 'display', 'table' )` if `#{id:tableObj}` is a table.
- In order to make tables responsive you need to include JS/CSS code for Responsive extension and initialize your tables accordingly, see [Responsive](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension for more details. Make sure to use [Download builder](http://datatables.net/download/index) to get the latest version.
- If you want to target multiple tables, you need to either use class or `table` tag name or repeat your initialization code for each table.
- You need to adjust column widths with [`columns.adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) and reinitialize Responsive extension  with [`responsive.recalc()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29) only when modal becomes visible.

For example:

```js
// Initialize all tables inside the modal
var table = x$('#{id:bootstrapModal} table').DataTable({
   responsive: true
});

// When modal window is shown
x$('#{id:bootstrapModal}').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   // Adjust column width and re-initialize Responsive extension
   x$('#{id:bootstrapModal} table').DataTable()
      .columns.adjust()
      .responsive.recalc();   
});

// Show modal window
x$('#{id:bootstrapModal}').modal('show');
```

Comment: this works, hoever I noticed that the dataTables tables get a width style property assigned which has the value of the ??? the dialogbox resides in. the modal which contains the datatables has a different width :-/